# CakePHP and Smarty Problems

Tags: php, cakephp, smarty

I am trying to use SmartyView with my Cakephp setup. I went here and used this class: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/icedcheese/2008/01/14/smarty-view-for-1-2

But on execution, I get this error:

Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property SmartyView::$Smarty has no effect [APP/views/smarty.php, line 58]

Fatal error: Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object

For this line:
        parent::__construct($controller);
        $this->Smarty = &new Smarty();

Has anyone else run into this/know what to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't [pass arguments to magic methods by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).

Change:

```
$this->Smarty = &new Smarty();
```

to:

```
$this->Smarty = new Smarty();
```